# Como quebrar linha entre tags CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, label, quebras-de-linha

Gostaria de saber como quebrar linha entre tags do mesmo tipo
Ex: Tenho varias labels e quero quebrar a linha entre elas, mas de forma que eu faça uma vez para todas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo que descrevo abaixo

```css
label{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>1</label>
<label>1</label>
<label>1</label>
<label>1</label>
```

Neste código, ele altera **TODOS** os labels da página. Se quiser só alterar um certo conjunto de labels, ponha-os dentro de uma div e ponha desta forma

```
<div class="topo">
<label>1</label>
    <label>1</label>
    <label>1</label>
    <label>1</label>
</div>
```

E nos estilos ponha da seguinte forma.

```
.topo > label{
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou direitinho, valeu

Comment: Dê a resposta como aprovada :)

Comment: Eu gostaria, mas não sei fazer

Comment: @JeanSimas Tem um botão com um certo junto ao numero de votos na minha resposta :)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar também desta forma

```css
label{
    display:block;
    clear:left;
}
```

```html
<label>Primeiro Texto</label>
<label>Segundo Texto</label>
<label>Terceiro Texto</label>
<label>Quarto Texto</label>
```

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Qual a função do `clear: left` na sua resposta?

Comment: Se for um objeto flutuante, o clear faz com que ele jogue o objeto para esquerda abaixo do objeto anterior.

Comment: Nice, deu certo

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .texto1 {word-wrap:normal}
    .texto2 {word-wrap:break-word}
    p {width:60%;max-width:400px}
</style>

<p class="texto1" style="border:2px solid orange">Seu texto</p>
<p class="texto2" style="border:2px solid orange">Seu texto</p>
```

Comment: Você pode comentar, em português mesmo, como esse exemplo responde ao que foi perguntado, e qual a diferença a ser esperada entre as duas formas?